# Is there something opposite of WidgetTester.scrollUntilVisible method in Flutter test?

Tags: flutter

As we know, the `WidgetTester.scrollUntilVisible` method scrolls a widget until it finds a target widget inside it. How can we achieve the opposite behavior, like scrolling a widget until a target widget is *invisible*?